# Cordova - Xcode - Build success but Plugin not found

Tags: cordova, ios11, xcode9, ipad-mini, plugman

we are using a worklflow where in we need to deploy the cordova app directly to the device.

After having include correctly a provisioning profile, build pass all test but the app in the ipad screen still remain black, the problem? Plugin are not include during the deploying process.

Here my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<widget id="com.private.booking" version="1.0.4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" versionCode="32" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>Private</name>
    <description>An app for booking from Private srl</description>
    <author email="sviluppo@bossitalia.com" href="https://www.bossitalia.com/">Contact us</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <engine name="android" spec="6.2.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.4.0" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="tel:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <access origin="mailto:*" launch-external="yes" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="android-versionCode" value="6.3.0" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1500" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23" />
        <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
        <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-market.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/icon-ldpi.png" target="res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/icon-mdpi.png" target="res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/icon-hdpi.png" target="res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png" />
        <resource-file src="res/icon/android/icon-xhdpi.png" target="res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png" />
        <icon src="res/icon/android/icon.png" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/android/xxxhdpi.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon57.png" width="57" height="57" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon114.png" width="114" height="114" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon180.png" width="180" height="180" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon120.png" width="120" height="120" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon167.png" width="167" height="167" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon152.png" width="152" height="152" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon1024.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon72.png" width="72" height="72" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon144.png" width="144" height="144" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon29.png" width="29" height="29" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="48" height="48" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon58.png" width="58" height="58" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon80.png" width="80" height="80" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon87.png" width="58" height="87" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon64.png" width="64" height="64" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon320.png" width="320" height="320" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon60.png" width="60" height="60" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon40.png" width="40" height="40" />
        <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash1024.png" width="768" height="1024" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash1136.png" width="640" height="1136" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash1334.png" width="750" height="1334" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash2048.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash2208.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash480.png" width="320" height="480" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash960.png" width="640" height="960" />
        <splash src="res/splashscreen/ios/splash2208.png" />
    </platform>
    <config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCalendarsUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>We are using available calendars on device to let the user add events booked by the application</string>
    </config-file>
    <config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>N.B. This feature is not fully implemented. We are using Photo Library to let the user add a profile picture to the application. Photo is sent to the server.
        </string>
    </config-file>
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-actionsheet" spec="2.3.3" />
    <plugin name="call-number" spec="0.0.2"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-event" spec="1.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.1.0"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="0.9.3"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.7"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="1.7.2"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="1.3.4"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="4.1.0"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.3.0"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-toast" spec="2.6.0"/>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="2.2.1"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="0.1.9"/> 
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="4.3.3"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="1.6.3"/>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="2.2.0"/>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="1.10.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-calendar" />
    <plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification" source="npm" spec="0.8.5"/>
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVStatusBar" onload="true" />
    </feature>
</widget>
```

Note that Android Studio correctly bind plugins injected by Cordova.

Please can you help me??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to build an ios app with Android Studio?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in the answer. I just found the problem: it was related to the cordova.js library inclusion that during the development phase is not required to the library injection provided by Android Studio. 

My case was related to the XCode.

Thanks anyway for the support dude :)